# Is Office365 now Sharepoint 2016?

Tags: 2013, office-365, 2016

I have a few SharePoint 2013 sites hosted on premise, and one Office365 site that is also SharePoint 2013. I know Office365 has changed the look and feel of the All Site Content page. Is this just a change for SharePoint 2013 for Office365, or is my Office365 site now a SharePoint 2016 site? Is this look and feel for All Site Content going to be available for on premise 2013 sites, or do I have to upgrade to SharePoint 2016 to see this new look and feel?

Answer (score 2):

You will have move to SharePoint 2016 and upgrade to the latest patch, but it'll be a while before you get the new look and feel (Modern Library Experience) in SP 2016. Recently SharePoint 2016 feature pack was announced and will contain:

> - Logging of administrative actions performed in Central Administration and with Windows PowerShell.
> - Enhancements to MinRole to support small environments.
> - A new OneDrive for Business user experience.
> - Custom tiles in the SharePoint app launcher.
> - Unified auditing across site collections on-premises and in Office 365.
> - Unified taxonomy across on-premises and Office 365.
> - OneDrive API 2.0.

Reference: [Announcing Feature Pack 1 for SharePoint Server 2016—cloud-born and future-proof](https://blogs.office.com/2016/09/26/announcing-feature-pack-1-for-sharepoint-server-2016-cloud-born-and-future-proof/)

Hopefully future feature packs will contain the new modern library experience and the new publishing page which is available in developer tenant when you use a workbench.aspx from the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) team.